# H2 Database error: Database "C:/Users/Albert Lam/test" not found

Tags: h2

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it.
I access the following url:
http://localhost:8080/h2-console/login.do?jsessionid=9d239c0cabb319e741ed69c619684266

[image]

When I click "connect" button I get below error:
Database "C:/Users/Albert Lam/test" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-200] 90149/90149 (Help)

This is my src/main/resources/data.sql:

```
                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer;
            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS accounts;

            CREATE TABLE `customer` (
              `customer_id` int AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
              `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
              `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
              `mobile_number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
              `create_dt` date DEFAULT NULL
            );

            CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
              `customer_id` int NOT NULL,
               `account_number` int AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
              `account_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
              `branch_address` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
              `create_dt` date DEFAULT NULL
            );

            INSERT INTO `customer` (`name`,`email`,`mobile_number`,`create_dt`)
             VALUES ('Eazy Bytes','tutor@eazybytes.com','9876548337',CURDATE());
             
            INSERT INTO `accounts` (`customer_id`, `account_number`, `account_type`, `branch_address`, `create_dt`)
             VALUES (1, 186576453, 'Savings', '123 Main Street, New York', CURDATE());
```

This is my pom.xml:


4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.5.8
 

com.eaztbytes
accounts
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
accounts
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>1.8</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-actuator


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>
                                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                </exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

        </project>
```

This is the output of the console:

.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __ _ \ \ \ 

( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ 

\/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
'  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
=========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/
:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.8)

2021-12-23 03:41:22.768  INFO 32160 --- [           main] c.e.accounts.AccountsApplication         : Starting AccountsApplication using Java 1.8.0_181 on DESKTOP-IJR725V with PID 32160 (C:\coding\workspace-Udemy-STS-Master Microservices with Java-Spring-Docker-Kubernetes\section4-18\workspace\accounts\target\classes started by Albert Lam in C:\coding\workspace-Udemy-STS-Master Microservices with Java-Spring-Docker-Kubernetes\section4-18\workspace\accounts)
2021-12-23 03:41:22.772  INFO 32160 --- [           main] c.e.accounts.AccountsApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-12-23 03:41:23.266  INFO 32160 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-12-23 03:41:23.310  INFO 32160 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 35 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-12-23 03:41:23.913  INFO 32160 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-12-23 03:41:23.920  INFO 32160 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-12-23 03:41:23.920  INFO 32160 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
2021-12-23 03:41:23.999  INFO 32160 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-12-23 03:41:23.999  INFO 32160 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1173 ms
2021-12-23 03:41:24.082  INFO 32160 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-12-23 03:41:24.177  INFO 32160 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-12-23 03:41:24.183  INFO 32160 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
2021-12-23 03:41:24.404  INFO 32160 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-12-23 03:41:24.452  INFO 32160 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.33
2021-12-23 03:41:24.603  INFO 32160 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-12-23 03:41:24.737  INFO 32160 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
2021-12-23 03:41:25.426  INFO 32160 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-12-23 03:41:25.437  INFO 32160 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-12-23 03:41:25.782  WARN 32160 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-12-23 03:41:26.148  INFO 32160 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2021-12-23 03:41:26.188  INFO 32160 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-12-23 03:41:26.203  INFO 32160 --- [           main] c.e.accounts.AccountsApplication         : Started AccountsApplication in 3.747 seconds (JVM running for 4.539)

Comment: Please reformat the console output

Comment: what are your application properties please share them